# Show data points on a Flex <mx:LineSeries>

Tags: apache-flex, charts

I'm using a graph with a `<mx:LineSeries>`. When I hover over the line it shows the data points as little circular points. How can I get these points to display all of the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To turn off the datatips for a particular series, set the series.interactive property to false.

Answer (score 6):

If you're using `<mx:LineSeries>`, then set the following property:

```
itemRenderer="mx.charts.renderers.CircleItemRenderer"
```

When constructing a LineSeries in ActionScript, then set the itemRenderer style on your LineSeries object before adding to the series array:

```
lineSeries.setStyle("itemRenderer", new ClassFactory(mx.charts.renderers.CircleItemRenderer));
```

Don't forget to...

```
import mx.charts.renderers.*;
```

You don't have to stick to the circle item renderer either, you can use any of the item renderers found in the renderers package.

Comment: thanks ill try this at somepoint. i wound up just using both a mx:plotseries and a mx:lineseries with the same data, then turned off data tips. is there anyway to turn data tips on for only one series in the chart?

Comment: Not that I know of, maybe a good subject for another question? :-)

Comment: you can use the showRenderer property of the itemRenderer class to do that.do the following  for each(var item:ChartItem in lineSeries.getAllChildren()){ (item as itemRenderer).showRenderer(false)} this will turn off the data points on --lineSeries--

Answer (score 2):

Nope, You're looking for

```
LineChart.showAllDataTips = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
showDataTips="true"
```