# Can I have a flex chart that has both plots and lines?

Tags: apache-flex, components, charts, data-visualization

Flex has a plotchart component and a linechart component.. but I am looking to make a chart that has lines connecting points as well as larger dots with rollover info. Is this easily possible? Would I have to create a custom component from scratch to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like what you need is a LineChart with `itemRenderer` rather than a mixed type chart.

Have a look at [Displaying data points in Flex Line chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480251/displaying-data-points-in-flex-line-chart)

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you want a chart with multiple series, of different display types.  This is pretty easy to do in Flex.  [This article](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7c6c.html) on multiple-series charts should get you started.

If you need Flex 3, try this [article](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=charts_types_11.html#227719).

Here is a *very* basic example of a plot+line chart.  It's not pretty at all, but it might give you an idea of how to get going.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
    <fx:Declarations>
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            [Bindable]
            private var plotData:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
                {xVal: 1, yVal: 5},
                {xVal: 2, yVal: 10},
                {xVal: 3, yVal: 15}
            ]);

            [Bindable]
            private var lineData:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
                {xVal: 1, yVal: 4},
                {xVal: 2, yVal: 1},
                {xVal: 3, yVal: 10}
            ]);
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <mx:LineChart id="myChart"
                  showDataTips="true"
                  height="250"
                  width="350">
        <mx:horizontalAxis>
            <mx:LinearAxis minimum="0" maximum="20" />
        </mx:horizontalAxis>
        <mx:verticalAxis>
            <mx:LinearAxis minimum="0" maximum="20" />
        </mx:verticalAxis>
        <mx:series>
            <mx:PlotSeries
                dataProvider="{plotData}"
                xField="xVal"
                yField="yVal">
            </mx:PlotSeries>
            <mx:LineSeries
                dataProvider="{lineData}"
                xField="xVal"
                yField="yVal">
            </mx:LineSeries>
        </mx:series>
    </mx:LineChart>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: that wasn't exactly what i was looking for in this question.. but would have been my next question, so thanks!!

Comment: @Damon, no problem :)  Glad you got your question answered!